# Wrong mailbox items being retrieved using Exchange Web Services managed API in C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to retrieve Inbox items from a specific mailbox (in which i have permissions), using Exchange Web Services managed API. I've tested the code first using my own email address via AutodiscoverUrl, and it works fine. However when i tried using the other email address, EWS still retrieves my **own** inbox items. Is this due to a cache or something?

My code is as follows:

```
    ExchangeService ex = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
    ex.AutodiscoverUrl("someothermailbox@company.com");

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = ex.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

    foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
         Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The e-mail address given to `AutodiscoverUrl` has nothing to do with which mailbox you are binding to.

There are (at least) two ways to get the inbox items from another users mailbox: Delegate access and impersonation.

If you have delegate access to the other users mailbox, you can specify the mailbox as a parameter in the call to `FindItems`:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = ex.FindItems(
    new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox("someothermailbox@company.com")), 
    new ItemView(10));
```

If you have the [permissions to impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) the other user, you can impersonate the other user when connecting to the EWS and the following call to `FindItem` will work on the inbox of the impersonated user:

```
ExchangeService ex = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
ex.AutodiscoverUrl("someothermailbox@company.com");
ex.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "someothermailbox@company.com");
ItemsResults<Item> findResults = ex.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));
```

Disclaimer: I have written the above code without actually testing it on a real Exchange server.

Comment: Thanks, since I have delegate access (and no impersonate permissions) I did your first approach and it worked!

Comment: It took me probably too much time to figure this out: 1) determine filter that includes target mailboxes: `Import-Module ActiveDirectory; get-aduser -filter * | where {$_.samaccountname -like "bob"}`, 2) create a management scope that includes target mailboxes `new-ManagementScope –Name bob_targetuser –RecipientRestrictionFilter {samaccountname -like "bob"}`; 3) assign the scope to the object ACL: `New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Name appimpersonationrole –Role ApplicationImpersonation –User usernamethatisallowedImpersonzationrights –CustomRecipientWriteScope bob_targetuser`

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I had to connect to mailbox using delegated access rather than impersonating user and of course Microsoft tutorial is pretty lacking in this field.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to send email using **only delegates** permission save the email first before sending it. it will set the smtp address that is required to send the message.

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1", "1234", "domain.com");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("user2@domain.com");

        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
        email.ToRecipients.Add("user2@domain.com");
        email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
        email.Body = new MessageBody("Sent by using the EWS Managed API");

        //save it first!
        email.Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts, "user1@domain.com"));

        email.Send();
```

i used it to avoid this error:
"When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids."

Comment: I was trying to send an e-mail from a shared account using impersonation, it wasn't working with the following error: "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user." Yet the Exchange Online website allows me to send e-mails as the shared user. This was bugging me until I found this answer, something pretty similar to this worked for what I was trying to do. Saving first is the key. Thank you. p.s. I'm using Save then SendAndSaveCopy.