# The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required error in outlook 365 service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outlook, office365

I am using the below Microsoft exchange service url to call the mailbox in my asp.net (4.5) C# application.

https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

The service and and its invocation is working fine while running from Visual Studio 2012.

But while hosting into IIS, I am getting the below error while service method invocation.

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

I am using the below code to invoke service:

```
   ExchangeService service = new 
   ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
   service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("praveen.vr@abc.com", "pwd", "dom");
   service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;           
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder rootFolder = 
   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(service, 
   WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
   rootFolder.Load();
```

Comment: have you check with addingImpersonation service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "email-address"); ?

Comment: I have tried, but now in VS, I m getting the error "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user." while service invocation. in IIS,I am getting the older error.

Comment: Is the working pc and the IIS in the same network?  The proxy authentication error usually occurs in a cooperate where outlook is implemented.  The port number for email is blocked in the network and requires port forwarding to a proxy server to allow the email port number to get through network.  This is to prevent hackers from forwarding email to their accounts.

Comment: "Is the working pc and the IIS in the same network?" - YES.
same network and same PC. Yes, its a cooperate mail box access.

Comment: for that you have to give necessary permissions in Office 365 and verify  "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user."  for permission

Comment: "you have to give necessary permissions in Office 365" - HOW?

Comment: have you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204411/the-account-does-not-have-permission-to-impersonate-the-requested-user answer