# How connect to Exchange Server via current Windows user credentials?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-authentication, exchangewebservices

**What the problem is?**

We have an Exchange Server 2010 SP2, IIS 7.5 and a console app in VS2013.

So we have done the following:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
ExchangeService EWSservice = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, timeZone);
//EWSservice.Url = new Uri("our url");
EWSservice.AutodiscoverUrl("my@mail.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

Both ways to define the url are working. 
Trying to set credentials:

```
EWSservice.Credentials = new WebCredentials("my@mail.com", "mypass");
```

This works too. But I want to connect by using the current Windows user credentials. Some code samples that had been used and crashed:

- `EWSservice.Credentials = new
  WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials);`
- `EWSservice.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`
- `EWSservice.Credentials =
  (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

**All of this has returned a 401 error: Unauthorized**

Additionally, I have edited the *app.config* like this - but it doesn't work:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <!--Other stuff-->
</authentication>
```

Then, I have read about authentication modes and found this:
[Windows User getting "access denied" from exchange server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154696/windows-user-getting-access-denied-from-exchange-server/36445219%2336445219][1])

The admin has set this delegate option, but the connection is still not working...

Now I have added this:

> `EWSservice.TraceEnabled = true;`

and I get an Exchange response in the console:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2016 07:59:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=bfab7cdda62a4bf8be5b43689199fcf6; expires=Thu, 20-Apr
-2017 07:59:02 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="our-domain"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So is the console App failing or are you trying to do this in ASP.net ? You might want to look at some request in fiddler and have a look at what Authentication headers its trying to use (eg Basic or NTLM). This is old but given the EWS Managed API still uses the Httpwebrequest still relative https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2004/07/28/authentication-in-web-services-with-httpwebrequest/

Comment: Its occuring in console App. Using HttpWebRequest return 401 error too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is possible but you may want to look at this
....

[How to get the current user's Active Directory details in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637486/how-to-get-the-current-users-active-directory-details-in-c-sharp)

Comment: And what kind of detail i'l get from AD? user mail is already known

Comment: Your question is: how to get the current user credentials am I mistaken?

If you already have the current user mail then I think you are approaching the problem the wrong way.
You need a SINGLE account credentials with permission to impersonate 
other accounts https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx
By doing this youll only have to have ONE username and password and then if you wan to access someone else's mailbox all you need is the mail